# VBA to find chart title and compare to string

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to write some VBA that will do a check to make sure that a chart has a specific title.  This is what I have right now.

```
Sub check_chart_title()

Worksheets(1).ChartObjects(3).Activate

With ActiveWorkbook.ActiveChart
    .HasTitle = True
    .ChartTitle.Select
End With

    If Selection = "Sales" Then 'code crashes here
        x = "good" 'proceed to the rest of the code, no chart title mismatch
    Else: x = "bad" 'specific action to take if there is a chart title mismatch
    End If
End Sub
```

I know that the issue is with the condition of the if statement.  But I haven't been able to find a way to run a condition on the chart title.  All I need is code that can identify if a chart title is equal to a certain string.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rather than select the chart title then test it, just put it in your `IF` statement.

```
With ActiveWorkbook.ActiveChart
    .HasTitle = True
    .ChartTitle.Select
    If .ChartTitle.Text = "Sales" Then 'code crashes here
        x = "good" 'proceed to the rest of the code, no chart title mismatch
    Else
    x = "bad" 'specific action to take if there is a chart title mismatch
    End If
End With
```

Comment: Works perfectly.  I was definitely over complicating this.  Thank you for the simple solution.

Comment: I have edited it to incorporate your `With` statement. But be careful if you do it this way as they rest of your code inside the if will be affected by the `With`.

Answer (score 2):

may be you're afte something like this:

```
Sub check_chart_title()        
    Worksheets(1).ChartObjects(3).Activate

    With ActiveChart
        .HasTitle = True
        .ChartTitle.Select
        If .name = "Sales" Then
            x = "good" 'proceed to the rest of the code, no chart title mismatch
        Else
            x = "bad" 'specific action to take if there is a chart title mismatch
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

You could always try this if you want to incorporate the `with`:

```
Dim myChart As Chartobject
set myChart = Sheets(1).ChartObjects(3)
With myChart
    if .ChartTitle.Text = "Sales" then
        x = "Good"
    Else
        x = "Bad"
    end if
    'Do some other stuff
end with
```

'